# Reset Yii2 form using jQuery without getting data required error

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, yii2, reset

Every way I have tried to reset the form doesn't work properly. Yii2 returns me the "data required" error after the field goes empty and one of them don't even goes empty.

This is the Yii2 action function.

```
public function actionListarausencias()
{
    $searchModel = new AusenciaSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $model = new Ausencia();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    }
    return $this->render('listarausencias', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

And this the javascript I use for sending the form.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var form = $('.formulario');
    var formData = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            form[0].reset();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

The source of the form

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <?php
            echo $form->field($model, 'idEmpleado')->label('Empleado')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'name' => 'idEmpleado',
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Empleado::find()->all(), 'idEmpleado', 'sDni'),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Empleados...'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
            ]);
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <?php
            echo $form->field($model, 'dFechaDesde')->label('Desde')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Desde...'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'autoclose'=>true,
                    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                ]
            ]);
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <?php
            echo $form->field($model, 'dFechaHasta')->label('Hasta')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Hasta...'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'autoclose'=>true,
                    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                ]
            ]);
        ?>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the source code of the form?

Comment: According to me this code is ok. Which input is showing the error exactly? The DatePicker or the Select2?

Comment: What do you mean by `"data required" error`?

Comment: When you set a atribute like "required" on the yii2 model and shows you the red message under the input field that says "this data is required".
"$form[0].reset();" its working, the inputs are empty after sending the form, but yii2 shows me those messages.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to send form twice, since your `.on('click'` handler does not stop regular button click event processing.

Note that clicking "submit" button is not the only way to submit form, so you may want to use `beforeSubmit` event instead, there are some good examples in [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-form-javascript#submitting-the-form-via-ajax) for that. Or at least put `return false` at the and of your event handler function.

`form[0].reset();` may reset simple form, but if you're using some JavaScript-based widgets, you may need to reset or reinit them separately.

Comment: I took off the button from the form so it doesn't send it. And just now I tryed again with beforeSubmit (it makes sense) but the errors of "data required" are still aparing after the "$form[0].reset()"
Yea, I thought that may be there is a way to reset the widgets from php, I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery val() function to reset those field

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
var form = $('.formulario');
var formData = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr("action"),
    type: form.attr("method"),
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        $("input").each( function(){
            $(this).val("");
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Something went wrong');
    }
});
```

});

or you can use

```
  $("#id_of_form input:type").val("");
```

here :type may be text, radio etc.

Comment: And what if the form contains a select tag or a textarea? This tricky answer is bad idea.

Comment: That does not work either. I have two kartik plugins. Slect2 and DatePicker.